# boost context: problems with exception propagation

Tags: exception, boost, executioncontext, boost-context

I'm using `boost::context::execution_context` (version 2) to write a C++ 11 library and I want to propagate exceptions from an `execution_context` to the calling execution.

I'd like to handle exceptions inside of a lambda that a client gives to my library function; however, I have encountered a strange issue where the exception is not handled by boost::context correctly in some cases.

This works as expected and is very similar to some of boost's [tests](https://github.com/boostorg/context/blob/fa50eb9d33ff8ea1bc8ab249f2272045ef6550bf/test/test_execution_context_v2.cpp#L602) and [examples](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/context/doc/html/context/ecv2.html#context.ecv2.exception_handling):

```cpp
TEST(execution_context, works) {
  // Client callable
  auto &&f = [](boost::context::execution_context<void> &&ctx) {
    throw std::runtime_error("help!");
    return std::move(ctx);
  };

  // Library code
  std::exception_ptr exc{};
  boost::context::execution_context<void> source(
      [&exc, &f](boost::context::execution_context<void> &&ctx) {
        try {
          ctx = f(std::move(ctx));
        } catch (boost::context::detail::forced_unwind const &) {
          throw;
        } catch (...) {
          exc = std::current_exception();
        }
        return std::move(ctx);
      });

  try {
    source = source();
    if (exc) {
      std::rethrow_exception(exc);
    }
  } catch (std::runtime_error const &) {
    std::cout << "Runtime Error Caught" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
[ RUN      ] execution_context.works
Runtime Error Caught
[       OK ] execution_context.works (0 ms)
```

But the following change does not work:

We add a class which wraps the `execution_context`:

```cpp
class Core {
  boost::context::execution_context<void> ctx_;

public:
  explicit Core(boost::context::execution_context<void> &&ctx)
      : ctx_{std::move(ctx)} {}

  auto &&done() { return std::move(ctx_); }
};
```

Now we make the same test as before but using the defined class:

```cpp
TEST(execution_context, fails) {
  // Client callable
  auto &&f = [](Core c) {
    throw std::runtime_error("help!");
    return c.done();
  };

  // Library code
  std::exception_ptr exc{};
  boost::context::execution_context<void> source(
      [&exc, &f](boost::context::execution_context<void> &&ctx) {
        try {
          ctx = f(Core(std::move(ctx)));
        } catch (boost::context::detail::forced_unwind const &) {
          throw;
        } catch (...) {
          exc = std::current_exception();
        }
        return std::move(ctx);
      });

  try {
    source = source();
    if (exc) {
      std::rethrow_exception(exc);
    }
  } catch (std::runtime_error const &) {
    std::cout << "Runtime Error Caught" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
[ RUN      ] execution_context.fails
unknown file: Failure
Unknown C++ exception thrown in the test body.
generators.t.tsk: /home/plewis/dpkg/refroot/amd64/opt/include/boost/context/detail/exception.hpp:37: boost::context::detail::forced_unwind::~forced_unwind(): Assertion `caught' failed.
zsh: abort (core dumped)  ./test.t.tsk
```

The only difference I notice is that the `execution_context` is contained in a class, and that causes the exception to be handled improperly. That makes no sense.

## Environment

I'm using GTest.

### Compiler

```
> g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 5.3.1 20160406 (Red Hat 5.3.1-6)
...
```

### System

```sh
> uname -a
Linux myhostname 2.6.32-642.6.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Oct 24 10:22:33 EDT 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

### Boost

`boost version 1.69.0 compiled for amd64`

Comment: @rafix07 changing the class member to an rvalue reference solved the issue I was experiencing. I still need to think about what you were saying about my move operations. If you create an answer, I'll give it credit.

Comment: I deleted my comment, it was not precise enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with moving `ctx` instance. Suppose you have two instances of `execution_context`:

```
execution_context src, dest;
// src and dest have some states
dest = std::move(src); // [1]
```

in [1] we are calling move assignment operator which "steals" resources of `src` and puts them into `dest`. If `execution_context` has a pointer, this pointer after moving will be 0 in `src` instance, so this object is useless and should not be used. Any operation on it may invoke some undesired behaviour.

In short version your code looks like:

```
void foo ()
{
  auto &&f = [](Core c) {};

  boost::context::execution_context<void> source(
      [&exc, &f](boost::context::execution_context<void> &&ctx) {
        // many lines        
        return std::move(ctx);
      });

    source = source();
}
```

we have two contexts, `foo` and body of lambda passed into source constructor. When `source()` is called the context is switched and `foo` is resumed and `lambda` is executed. In this lambda context of `foo` is destroyed because it is just moved into `Core` instance. So how do you want to resume `foo` execution? You cannot.

Problem with Core:

```
class Core {
  boost::context::execution_context<void> ctx_;

public:
  explicit Core(boost::context::execution_context<void> &&ctx)
      : ctx_{std::move(ctx)} {} // [2]

  auto &&done() { return std::move(ctx_); }
};
```

`ctx_` is non-reference data member, so in [2] move constructor is called which steals ctx's resources.

The next issue would be with `done` method if it didn't throw exception:
Look at this:

```
  auto &&f = [](Core c)
  {
    // throw std::runtime_error("help!"); COMMENTED
    return c.done();
  };
```

`c` is local inside lambda. `done` returns reference to data member of `Core` which is destroyed when lambda ends. So you have dangling reference.

Fix: you can just store reference to context inside `Core`. Then original context of `foo` will be safe.